# Simple Handmade PHP Template Engine not working! Help Please

Tags: php, templates, constructor, abstract-class

These are the class definitions

```
<?php
  abstract class MyTemplate {

  protected $arrayOfSpaces;
  protected $arrayOfVariables;
  protected $output;

  protected abstract function __construct(); 

  function outputHTML(){
    echo $output; //Apparently, the problem is HERE. <<<<>>>>>
  }
}
  class MyTemplateMain extends MyTemplate {
   function __construct(){
     $this->output="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"
             \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
             <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
             I love Rock n Roll!!!
             </body>
             </html>";
    }

  }
?>
```

And this is where I launch this page

```
<?php 
  require_once("view/templates.php");

  $page=new MyTemplateMain();
  $page->outputHTML();



?>
```

Doesn't work, though. Just shows a blank page, without the String I love rock n roll which was supposed to appear in the body.

I'm sure there are better ways to implement templates but I just want to figure out why this particular example doesn't work

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

PS: The quotes are all duly escaped and the file paths are ok too

Comment: `this.$output` should be `$this->output`

Comment: I misspelled it when typing it here... The script I'm running is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change :

```
 function outputHTML(){
    echo $output;
  }
```

to :

```
 function outputHTML(){
    echo $this->output;
  }
```

Comment: Hm... PHP can't guess which variable I'm talking about if i don't use $this? Or is this just stylewise?

Comment: PHP doesn't even try to guess. `$this` is always required.

Comment: in the context of object, $this always referes to, well... that object. But you can only access it from the inside of the object.

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is weird, try this

```
  abstract class MyTemplate {

  protected $arrayOfSpaces;
  protected $arrayOfVariables;
  protected $output;

  public abstract function __construct(); 

  function outputHTML(){
    echo $this->output;
  }
}
  class MyTemplateMain extends MyTemplate {
    public function __construct(){
     $this->output="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"
             \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
             <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
             I love Rock n Roll!!!
             </body>
             </html>";
    }

  }

$page=new MyTemplateMain();
$page->outputHTML();
```

Comment: Hmm you mean everything in one file? That shouldn't be the source of the problem, but Ok. Done that. STill doesn't work.. I'm thinking I must have overlooked some tiny detail..Thx anyway

Comment: no sorry :) you got me wrong, the file wasn't the Problem (but i did it in one to save time). First i don't know any OOP Angle PHP5 (or 5.3) has, but i mainly changed the way you access the variables ($this->output insteadt of just $output or this.$output ) and changed the __constructur to public

Comment: I think I solved it. I guess you must name the function ABSTRACT PROTECTED rather than PROTECTED ABSTRACT. Apparently, the "abstact" keyword comes first

Comment: thats better coding style, but for the parser (as far as i know and tested it under pgp 5.3) it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try `$base->output` instead of `$this->output`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't know why but now it's working. I rewrote it some times so I must've done some correctly even though unintended. Here is the code if anyone wants to have alook and compare the versions. Thanks all

```
abstract class MyTemplate {

protected $arrayOfSpaces;
protected $arrayOfVariables;
protected $output;


function outputHTML(){
    echo $this->output;
}

}

class MyTemplateMain extends MyTemplate {

function __construct(){
    $this->output="<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"
             \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
             <html>
             <head>
             </head>
             <body>
             I love Rock n Roll!!!
             </body>
             </html>";
}
}
```

Comment: if first example in `outputHTML` function you have `echo $output;` which echo undefined variable and in second you have `echo $this->output;` which output object field.

Comment: the problem is not the order of abstract and protected, its the handling of variables in class context